How to deploy a custom Docker image to an Azure Web App (Linux container) slot
We have a custom docker image based on Python and docker file using port 5000 to expose within the container. Also we have created a private Azure Webapp service based on Linux container in our Spoke with production and staging slot on it.
We are looking for a way to directly deploy this custom created docker image from the server to Azure Web app (Linux container) slot, so that
after each docker image version creation, we can deploy the image to this Webapp slot directly and the application can be accesses over https endpoint url.
We were referring the MS document to identify the web app deployment command and passing the docker image tag, but couldn't find any az command to achieve this task to deploy the docker image built to the appservice slot

Please share more details about the issue you are facing?

Question modified. basically looking for some kind of automation or az cli command to deploy the custom docker image to webapp slot directly.

Use ```az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name MyDockerCustomImage --docker-registry-server-password StrongPassword --docker-registry-server-url https://{azure-container-registry-name}.azurecr.io --docker-registry-server-user DockerUserId --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
(or)


```az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name MyDockerCustomImage --docker-registry-server-url https://{azure-container-registry-name}.azurecr.io --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup



Other way az webapp create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --plan MyAppServicePlan --name MyWebApp --deployment-container-image-name MyACR.azurecr.io/myimage:latest

Are you having problem with Container Apps or App Services?
To deploy to Azure Container Apps, I use these scripts:
# Step 6: Create a Container Apps environment
Write-Host "`nCreating a Container Apps environment named '${environmentName}'"
$containerEnv = az containerapp env create `
                         --name $environmentName  `
                         --resource-group $rgname `
                         --location $location `
                         --logs-workspace-id $workspaceId `
                         --logs-workspace-key $workspaceKey `
                         --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host "Container Apps Environment created"

# Step 7: Create Azure Container App for CloudDebugger
# Set DEPLOY_TRIGGER to a random value to force a redeployment
Write-Host "`nCreating Azure Container App for CloudDebugger"
$randomValue = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$container = az containerapp create `
    --name $containerAppName `
    --environment $environmentName `
    --resource-group $rgname `
    --user-assigned $identityId `
    --registry-identity $identityId `
    --registry-server "${acrname}.azurecr.io" `
    --image "${acrname}.azurecr.io/${imagename}:latest" `
    --target-port 8080 `
    --ingress external `
    --cpu 0.25 `
    --memory 0.5 `
    --min-replicas 1 `
    --max-replicas 1 `
    --env-vars AZURE_CLIENT_ID=$clientId DEPLOY_TRIGGER=$randomValue `
    --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
$containerId = $container.id 

if you have problems with deploying to App Services, then I have a blog post about that here:
Deploy Container to Azure App Services with System-Assigned Identity
Where I use this command to update the container deployment:
$imagePath = "${acrname}.azurecr.io/${imagename}:latest"
Write-Host "`n`nChange the service to use the container ${imagePath}."
az webapp config container set `
  --name $AppServiceName_container_linux `
  --resource-group $rgname `
  --container-image-name $imagePath `
  --output json | ConvertFrom-Json


We haven't configured the Appservice with ACR integration as of now. But what we are trying to achieve is directly deploy the docker image from the build server using az webapp command or any other way, where we can pass the acr endpoint and image tag. Also we are performing this in Linux build server and looking for az bash based commands or scripts

See my blog post, it contains scripts to do all the steps using the az commands. let me know if you have any specific question
